# Index.php put in a pre tag in Apache

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, lamp

I am trying to get a moodle server (LAMP stack) up and running. I followed these instructions: https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Step-by-step_Installation_Guide_for_Ubuntu.

When I navigate to my page, it places the whole index.php in a `<pre>` tag, so the code is just displayed and not executed. I looked in my /var/www/html/moodle directory and there is no `<pre>` tag in the index.php.

I am thinking that Apache is not playing nice with PHP and I need to adjust something, but I'm a bit new to LAMP and don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to serve the php files by following directions here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Specifically, modifying the dir.conf to put index.php first

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
          DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Also installing the following libraries:

libapache2-mod-php5
php5-mcrypt